# SQL server high availability solutions in Amazon AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, failovercluster

I am in the process of migrating to Amazon AWS and need a SQL server high availability solution. The current licence that I have is SQL standard 2016.
At this time Amazon does not support shared volumes for Windows instances. Therefore, I am not able to do a regular SQL cluster fail over solution. This is the one where if the entire server goes down the stand by server picks up the slack and continues writing to the same storage. My only option is high availability always on basic groups. As I am starting to get familiar with this feature I find it very maintenance intensive and can see it becoming a problem when dealing with thousands of databases. In my case I have about 5k databases mostly small in size 600mb or less each. My question is Amazon not a viable hosting environment for a full SQL fail over solution. Is the high availability always on basic groups one per database a viable solution?

Comment: This isnt on-topic for this [**forum**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 try https://dba.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Moritz What would you use ?? "site" ?

Comment: Look into SQL Server on RDS

Comment: @JohnHanley RDS has some severe limitations with how many databases per instance.

Comment: @CodeMilian. Yes you are correct. For your use case, not good. Sorry for overlooking the number of databases that you need to support.